# Not able to call JQuery function to select dynamically returned textbox

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

To table's body I am dynamically passing table from js file.
      For a column , I returned textbox as follows:

```
  function (oObj) {
  return '<div id=\"uniform-chkPerOverage\">
  <span ><input type=\"textbox\"  id=\"txtPerOverage1\" 
  value=\"'+ oObj.aData.Per_Overage+ '\"
  class=\"clsPer_Overage\" />  
  </span>  </div>'
  + '<input type=\"hidden\"  id=\"hdnEDIID\" value=\"' +
  oObj.aData.inID + '\"/>'
```

I tried this for above textbox in jS file's Initialization event which  is not getting called:

```
    $('div.clsPer_Overage').keyup(function (event) {
    alert("1");
   });
```

For Already present textbox , similar Jquery code running fine .
       Why I am unable to call it. Is that because, the textbox      is .dynamically returned?

My Browser rendered structure of table is as follows:
TEll me how can I select that textbox to fire keyup event.
[image]
PLease guide.
Thanks

Comment: You have put $('div.clsPer_Overage').keyup(function (event) {
    alert("1");
   }); in document.ready()?

Comment: I had tried that also. But it did not work.

Comment: Can you not just use `$('.clsPer_Overage').keyup(function (event) { alert("1");});`?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery events cannot be bound automatically for dynamically rendered html elements. You will need to use **.on** function as follow:

```
$('.clsPer_Overage').on('keyup', function() {
    alert("1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I did this and it worked .
Thanks all those who suggested.